# Quality issues with mov to mp4 video conversion through handbrake

Tags: video, windows-media-player, mp4

I am converting mov video files to mp4 through handbrake tool but the video quality is getting disturbed in the windows media player. It is working fine with the vlc player. How do I resolve this issue. I need to convert these videos to a very low video size

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a computer hardware problem. I have had this problem as well, but there was no way of stopping it. Try viewing the videos/audios on a different, more powerful computer.

Hope this helps.